# How to instantiate a class correctly using Depency Injector in a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, dependency-injection

In my Flask app, I'm using Dependency Injection and here's what my app looks like. I have a service which uses S3 as a datastore and I'm trying to instantiate my app with the service injected (which is injected with the S3 client). However, it doesn't look like the S3 client is correctly instantiated or I'm doing something wildly different.

`containers.py`

```
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(modules=[".routes", ".scheduler"])

    config = providers.Configuration()
    s3_config = dict()
    s3_config["path"], s3_config["filters"] = config.get("s3_bucket"), [("member_status_nm", "=", "ACTIVE")]
    
    s3_repository = providers.Singleton(S3Repository, s3_config)

    my_service = providers.Factory(
        MyService, config, S3Repository
    )
```

Here's my `S3Repository`:

```
import logging
import sys
import time

import some_library as lib

class S3Repository:
    def __init__(self, s3_config):
        self.path, self.columns, self.filters = \
            s3_config.get("path", ""), s3_config.get("columns", []), s3_config.get("filters", [])

    def fetch(self):
        # execute fetch
        result = lib.some_fetch_method(self.path, self.columns, self.filters)

        return result
```

and `MyService`:

```
import #all relevant imports here

class MyService:
    
    def __init__(self, config: dict, s3_repository: S3Repository) -> None:
        
        logging.info("HealthSignalService(): initializing")

        self.config = config["app"]["health_signal_service"]

        
        # prepare s3_repository for the service
        self.s3_repository = s3_repository
        self.s3_repository.columns, self.s3_repository.filters, self.s3_repository.path = \
            ["x","y"], ["x1","y1"], "file_path"

        
    def fetch_data(self) -> None:

        try:
            summary_result = self.s3_repository.fetch()
        except (FileNotFoundError, IOError) as e:
            
           print("failure")
        return summary_result
   
   def get_data(memberId):
        sth = self.fetch_data()
        return sth.get(memberId)
```

and finally tying it together in my `routes.py`:

```
@inject
@auth.login_required
def get_signals(
        my_service: MyService = Provide[
            Container.my_service
        ],
):
    content = request.json
    member_id = content["memberId"]
    result = my_service.get_signals(member_id)
    return jsonify(result)
```

When I hit my API endpoint I see this error:

```
summary_result = self.s3_repository.fetch()
TypeError: fetch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How do I correctly initialize my S3 client while using dependency injection?

Comment: `s3_repository` is probably just the class and not an instance

Comment: So, am I instantiating/wiring/injecting it wrong?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with this package. It doesn't *look* like you're doing it wrong based on the [Factory pattern](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/api/providers.html#dependency_injector.providers.Factory) that they reference

Comment: I think you need `s3_repository` to be the result of [`singleton()`](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/api/providers.html#dependency_injector.providers.Singleton)

Comment: So in your code, maybe `s3_repository = providers.Singleton(S3Repository, s3_config)()`

Comment: @C.Nivs `s3_repository` is the result of a Singleton :)

Comment: and my inexperience now rears its head :)